# Contradiction in Davis–Putnam–Logemann–Loveland (DPLL) Method?!

Tags: logic, computer-science, artificial-intelligence, satisfiability

As we see on page $10,11$ and $12$ on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5ZWLgcsc-8C&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=dpll%20unit%20clause%20fail%20pure%20literal%20solution&source=bl&ots=YtUAtArsmV&sig=rTwmxfeNvBVPSmrYmQL7ETCeskY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp9vDXlb_NAhUIYpoKHd3fBN0Q6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=dpll%20unit%20clause%20fail%20pure%20literal%20solution&f=false) we know about Unit Clause (**UC**) and Pure Literal (**PL**) in DPLL Algorithms. in the following example  if assign value $0$ to variables is prior to assign $1$ to variables, **PL** and **UC** is used, but I think just **UC** is used.

> $\{\lnot A \lor B \lor C\}, \{A \lor \lnot B \lor C\}, \{A \lor B \lor \lnot C\}, \{A \lor B \lor C\}$

any idea why our solution is differ with answer sheet that say **PL** and **UC** is used?

Edit:
I think we have following diagram that in node (3) we can use PL or UC.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Phi$ the initial set of four *clauses* as above.

> **Def 15**. A *pure literal* is a literal $l$ that appears in at least one clause of $\Phi$ while $\lnot l$ doers not appear in any clause of $\Phi$.

Thus, initially, there are no pure literals.

> **Def 16**. A *unit clause* is a clause with exactly one unknown literal in it.

Thus, initially, there are no unit clauses.

So, you have to apply $DPLL(\Phi)$ selecting e.g. the variable $A$ and branching with:

> $DPLL(\Phi|_{A=0})$ and $DPLL(\Phi|_{A=1})$.

For the left branch:

1) $\{ 1∨B∨C \}, \{ 0∨¬B∨C \}, \{ 0∨B∨¬C \}, \{ 0∨B∨C \}$.

Now I suppose you can simplify, according to the rules,:

> $1 \lor p \equiv 1$ and $0 \lor p \equiv p$,

to:

1') $\{ 1 \}, \{ ¬B∨C \}, \{ B∨¬C \}, \{ B∨C \}$.

After the first step, again neither pure literals nor unit clauses in this branch.

Then we can go on with $B$; for $B=0$ we have:

1'1) $\{ ¬C \}, \{ C \}$

and for $B=1$:

1'2) $\{ C \}$.

Now we can apply either *PL* or *UL*, satisfying this branch.

For the right branch:

2) $\{ 0∨B∨C \}, \{ 1∨¬B∨C \}, \{ 1∨B∨¬C \}, \{ 1∨B∨C \}$.

Simplifying again, we have:

2') $\{ B∨C \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 1 \}$.

Here we can apply the *Pure-Literal rule* setting both $B$ and $C$ to $1$, proving again that the formula is SAT.

Comment: very nice answer, but one misunderstanding point is we can use PL or UC, am I right?

Comment: Would you please see my updates? is it okey?

Comment: I think you traverse the tree row by row but DPLL is Depth First.

Comment: I wait for your answer...

Comment: So your answer is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: you first should check node (1) in my figure, then (2) and finally (3)

Comment: Last answer are different. I think yo do first step in first row and then go to right branch. the order is important.

Comment: Are u here? Why you didn't answer me? would you please continue in chat?